# Check If comment author is registered

Tags: comments, author

It should be simple, but I tried some codes, none does the trick. Searched on Google, nothing there either. 
 Simply check if the comment author is a registered user (so I can add some code for it), if it's not registered show nothing.

This should do the trick `if( empty($comment_author_nickname) && empty($comment_author_email) )` but I don't know how to get that information

thank you

Comment: updated the question with the code. I searched for 'Check If comment author is registered' and variations. no result gets me what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you mean this kind of check:

```
if( $comment->user_id > 0 ) {
    // Registered comment author
}
```

in your comment's template callback.

This is determined in the the `wp-comments-post.php` file:

```
$commentdata = compact('comment_post_ID', ..., 'user_ID' );
$comment_id = wp_new_comment( $commentdata );
```

but it's not obvious where the `user_ID` variable comes from, since this variable is not defined in that file.

So this is actually picking up the global variable `$user_ID` or `$GLOBALS['user_ID']` behind our back ;-)

Comment: yes indeed, as simple as that, just a simple check. it works. thank you

Comment: Great answer. Did not think about that.

Comment: I finally found the origin of that value, "hidden" as a global variable in the `wp-comments-post.php` file ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any safe and reliable method to do this. In my honest opinion, this is also something that I would discourage

My biggest concerns here are

- Anyone can enter a fake email or nickname that can match the details of an already registered member
- By doing this, an unregistered user might be able to get access to a registered member's details
- What method are you going to use to match info entered into the comment form against info from all your registered members

### SOLUTION

Your best and safest method to achieve this would be to prompt a user to login if they are an already registered member. Apart from this, as I said, I cannot see any other safe and reliable method to achieve this

Comment: I see. But I simply use this condition just to show a field for registered user, and nothing for unregistered. User rank from a plugin.